# What is the difference between both the queries described below

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

When I am using the query `"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE " + "id = ? and password = ? and verified = true"` to retrieve the row which is having the specified 'id' and 'password', it is returning me that the id does not exist in the table (but I know that it exists). But when I am using the query `"SELECT count(*) FROM Customer WHERE " + "id = ? and password = ? and verified = true"`, it is returning that the id exists in the table. 
So, I not getting that what is the actual difference between both of these queries...

```
con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM Customer WHERE " + "id = ? and password = ? and verified = true");
pst.setString(1, obj.getId());
pst.setString(2, obj.getPassword());
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: COUNT(*) will give a result (of 0) even if there is no match. Are you checking the resulting value to confirm existence, or only that there is a result?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)...` will always return 1 row, even if the count it returns is 0. Whereas `SELEC *` may return an empty result set (zero rows). Oh, I posted this simultaneously with Uueerdo... :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very clear with what you mean, when you say "it is returning that the id exists in the table."

Exactly what is it returning? And how are you determining that, with that return, it shows an ID exists in the table?

Your second query will always return at least 1 row, where the first row will have a column of: "count_of_x" or something along those lines, and it will show a 0 for the value, if nothing was found.

The count query just counts how many rows matches your condition. If there is no matches, 0 is returned.

It seems like you are assuming that the id exists, because the count is returning a single row, and without looking into the value of the row, you are determining that that means there is an id.

Why dont you just try a simple query:

> `Select * from customers where id = ?`

Without the password or verified, to see if someone with that id actually exists.

Comment: This should be in the comments, not an answer.

Comment: This is fine as an answer.

Comment: "select * ........" is not working right. It is returning object of ResultSet which does not contain any row (but the specified id exists in the database).